# Laravel passport install on dynamic database

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating database for each client registration in my laravel application. I have installed passport for authorization. I have successfully created database and ran migration for passport also. The passport:install command is not working for newly created database. Is there any way to run command passport:install for my new database.

```
  $this->info(sprintf("Dropping database if exists : %s", $dbName));
            DBHelper::drop($dbName);

            $this->info("Setting up database for client");

            //Create migration table
            Artisan::call("migrate:install", array(
                "--database" => DBHelper::connect($dbName)
            ));

            //Run migration
            Artisan::call('migrate',
                array('--path' => 'database/migrations/client',
                    '--database' => DBHelper::connect($dbName))); //DBHelper::connect($dbName) : Create new database config and then DB::reconnect()

            //Install passport migration
            Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => 'vendor/laravel/passport/database/migrations']);
            //Install passport
            Artisan::call('passport:install');

            //Populate database
            Artisan::call('db:seed',
                array('--database' => DBHelper::connect($dbName)));
```

Answer (score 1):

After creating database use bellow commands for creating migrations and install passport.

```
Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', ['--seed' => true]);

Artisan::call('migrate',['--path' => 'vendor/laravel/passport/database/migrations','--force' => true]);

shell_exec('php ../artisan passport:install');
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would use the following code in your controller to excute an Artisan call:

Artisan::call('passport:install');
However, this doesn't work on passport:install and you will get the error:

> There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace

To fix this you must add the following code to boot method at AppServiceProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Console\ClientCommand;
use Laravel\Passport\Console\InstallCommand;
use Laravel\Passport\Console\KeysCommand;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Passport::routes();

    /*ADD THIS LINES*/
    $this->commands([
        InstallCommand::class,
        ClientCommand::class,
        KeysCommand::class,
    ]);
}
```